# Matching with regex

Tags: match

I'm reading an intro book on Ruby and I'm having trouble understanding how regex works. There's an example that says to write a regular expression that matches the following strings:

```
1)rby
2)rb
```

The closest I could get was writing this:

```
rb+y*
```

How can I edit my expression so it matches? Unfortunately the book I'm using does not provide the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check for the start and end of the string

```
^rb+y*$
```

Answer (score 2):

The string must begin with exactly one `"r", so we start with

```
/\Ar
```

`\A` being a beginning-of-string anchor. Next, there are one or two `"b"`'s.

```
/\Arb{1,2}
```

This may optionally be followed by one `"y"`.

```
/\Arb{1,2}y?
```

Lastly, no other characters can follow the optional `"y"`, so we add an end-of-string anchor and terminate the regex.

```
r = /\Arb{1,2}y?\z/

%w| rby rb rbby rbb |.all? { |s| s =~ r }     #=> true
%w| ruby rbyry rrby bby |.any? { |s| s =~ r } #=> false
```

`r` is not the only regex that works. `/\Arb+y?\z/` and `/\Arb+y*\z/` meet the test as well.

A small point: `\A` and `\z` are beginning-of-*string* and end-of-*string* anchors, respectively, whereas `^` and `$` are beginning-of-*line* and end-of-*line* anchors. Here each string consists of a single line, so either set of anchors can be used. Although you will often see the end-of-line anchors used for single-line strings, I believe most Rubiests believe your code is made clearer by always using end-of-string anchors when it is a string you are anchoring, regardless of whether is is comprised of one line or multiple lines.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to match the start and end of the string/line:

```
/^rb+y?$/
```

You can [test this and play with it here](http://rubular.com/r/IWgw4s3Kp3) using Rubular.

The book you're reading should spell out both of those characters, but in case it doesn't:

- `^` at the beginning of an expression matches the beginning of the line. Anywhere else in the expression it behaves differently.
- `$` at the end of an expression matches the end of a line. Again, anywhere else in the expression it behaves differently.

Comment: I notice you changed the `y*` to `y?`; there's no test case for `rbbyy`, so I don't know which would be correct, although hazarding a guess, `y?` may be a better example.

Comment: @KenY-N Correct, a `*` and `+` are greedy matchers and I've found it's better to err on the side of caution when you can. Of course, `rbb?y?` would have worked as well.  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯